# How to optimize long SQL statements?

Tags: mysql, database, optimization, database-design

In my project, there are several long SQL statements. They are more than 100 lines and multiple select, join and nested union. It is hard to read and it is necessary to optimize.
Which aspect should  I pay attention to? Table structure, SQL statements itself or something others? How to optimize these long SQL statements? Any suggestions are welcome.

Following is a piece of code.

```
select p.id,p.from_zone fromzone,p.to_zone tozone,p.action,p.status,saw.srcaddr,daw.dstaddr,aw2.protocol,case when aw2.port=';' then ' ' else aw2.port end port                            
from policy p join (select sa.id,sa.device,concat(replace(group_concat(sa.nameshow),',',';&lt;br /&gt;'),';') srcaddr from                                          
                                (select sai.id,sai.device,sai.nameshow,max(sai.flag) flagw from
                                        (select psa1.id,psa1.device,a1.network nameshow,case when a1.from_network&lt;=#{srcAddr} and a1.to_network&gt;=#{srcAddr} then 1 else 0 end flag from policy_source_destination_addr psa1 join address a1 on psa1.address=a1.name and psa1.device=a1.device and psa1.zone=a1.zone where psa1.device=#{deviceName} and psa1.direction='source'
                                         union
                                         select psa2.id,psa2.device,psa2.address nameshow,case when a2.from_network&lt;=#{srcAddr} and a2.to_network&gt;=#{srcAddr} then 1 else 0 end flag from policy_source_destination_addr psa2 join address_set as1 on psa2.address=as1.name and psa2.device=as1.device and psa2.zone=as1.zone
                                                                                join address a2 on as1.device=a2.device and as1.zone=a2.zone and as1.address=a2.name
                                                                                where psa2.device=#{deviceName} and psa2.direction='source'
                                         union
                                         select psa3.id,psa3.device,psa3.address nameshow,case when a5.from_network&lt;=#{srcAddr} and a5.to_network&gt;=#{srcAddr} then 1 else 0 end flag from policy_source_destination_addr psa3 join address_set as3 on psa3.address=as3.name and psa3.device=as3.device and psa3.zone=as3.zone
                                                                                join address_set as4 on as3.device=as4.device and as3.zone=as4.zone and as3.address=as4.name
                                                                                join address a5 on as4.device=a5.device and as4.zone=a5.zone and as4.address=a5.name
                                                                                where psa3.device=#{deviceName} and psa3.direction='source'
                                         union
                                         select psa3.id,psa3.device,psa3.address nameshow,1 flag from policy_source_destination_addr psa3 where psa3.device=#{deviceName} and psa3.direction='source' and upper(psa3.address)='ANY'
                                         ) sai
                                 group by sai.id,sai.device,sai.nameshow
                                ) sa
                    group by sa.id,sa.device having max(sa.flagw)=1) saw on p.id=saw.id and p.device=saw.device
              join (select da.id,da.device,concat(replace(group_concat(da.nameshow),',',';&lt;br /&gt;'),';') dstaddr from
                                (select dai.id,dai.device,dai.nameshow,max(dai.flag) flagw from
                                        (select pda1.id,pda1.device,a3.network nameshow,case when a3.from_network&lt;=#{dstAddr} and a3.to_network&gt;=#{dstAddr} then 1 else 0 end flag from policy_source_destination_addr pda1 join address a3 on pda1.address=a3.name and pda1.device=a3.device and pda1.zone=a3.zone where pda1.device=#{deviceName} and pda1.direction='destination'
                                         union
                                         select pda2.id,pda2.device,pda2.address nameshow,case when a4.from_network&lt;=#{dstAddr} and a4.to_network&gt;=#{dstAddr} then 1 else 0 end flag from policy_source_destination_addr pda2 join address_set as2 on pda2.address=as2.name and pda2.device=as2.device and pda2.zone=as2.zone
                                                                                join address a4 on as2.device=a4.device and as2.zone=a4.zone and as2.address=a4.name
                                                                                where pda2.device=#{deviceName} and pda2.direction='destination'
                                         union
                                         select pda3.id,pda3.device,pda3.address nameshow,case when a6.from_network&lt;=#{dstAddr} and a6.to_network&gt;=#{dstAddr} then 1 else 0 end flag from policy_source_destination_addr pda3 join address_set as5 on pda3.address=as5.name and pda3.device=as5.device and pda3.zone=as5.zone
                                                                                join address_set as6 on as5.device=as6.device and as5.zone=as6.zone and as5.address=as6.name
                                                                                join address a6 on as6.device=a6.device and as6.zone=a6.zone and as6.address=a6.name
                                                                                where pda3.device=#{deviceName} and pda3.direction='destination'
                                         union
                                         select pda3.id,pda3.device,pda3.address nameshow,1 flag from policy_source_destination_addr pda3 where pda3.device=#{deviceName} and pda3.direction='destination' and upper(pda3.address)='ANY'
                                         ) dai
                                 group by dai.id,dai.device,dai.nameshow
                                ) da
                    group by da.id,da.device having max(da.flagw)=1) daw on p.id=daw.id and p.device=daw.device
              join (select distinct ai.id,ai.device from                                         
                             (select pa1.id,pa1.device
                              from policy_application pa1 join application ap1 on pa1.device=ap1.device and pa1.application=ap1.name
                              where pa1.device=#{deviceName} and upper(ap1.protocol)=#{protocol} and if(instr(ap1.destination_port,'-')=0,ap1.destination_port=#{port},substr(ap1.destination_port,1,instr(ap1.destination_port,'-')-1)+0&lt;=#{port} and substr(ap1.destination_port,instr(ap1.destination_port,'-')+1)+0&gt;=#{port})
                              union
                              select pa2.id,pa2.device
                              from policy_application pa2 join application_set aps1 on pa2.application=aps1.name and pa2.device=aps1.device
                                                                 join application ap2 on aps1.application=ap2.name and aps1.device=ap2.device
                                                                 where pa2.device=#{deviceName} and upper(ap2.protocol)=#{protocol} and if(instr(ap2.destination_port,'-')=0,ap2.destination_port=#{port},substr(ap2.destination_port,1,instr(ap2.destination_port,'-')-1)+0&lt;=#{port} and substr(ap2.destination_port,instr(ap2.destination_port,'-')+1)+0&gt;=#{port})
                              union
                              select pa3.id,pa3.device
                              from policy_application pa3 join application_set aps2 on pa3.application=aps2.name and pa3.device=aps2.device
                                                                 join application_term apt1 on aps2.application=apt1.name and aps2.device=apt1.device
                                                                 where pa3.device=#{deviceName} and upper(apt1.protocol)=#{protocol} and if(instr(apt1.destination_port,'-')=0,apt1.destination_port=#{port},substr(apt1.destination_port,1,instr(apt1.destination_port,'-')-1)+0&lt;=#{port} and substr(apt1.destination_port,instr(apt1.destination_port,'-')+1)+0&gt;=#{port})
                              union
                              select pa4.id,pa4.device
                              from policy_application pa4 join application_map am4 on pa4.application=am4.name
                              where pa4.device=#{deviceName} and upper(am4.protocol)=#{protocol} and (if(am4.portvalue is null,1=1,if(length(am4.portvalue)-length(replace(am4.portvalue,'#',''))=2,SUBSTRING_INDEX(am4.portvalue, '#', 1)+0&lt;=#{port} and SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(am4.portvalue, '#', -2), '#', 1)+0&gt;=#{port},SUBSTRING_INDEX(am4.portvalue, '#', 1)+0=#{port} or SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(am4.portvalue, '#', -2), '#', 1)+0=#{port})))
                              ) ai
                    ) aw on p.id=aw.id and p.device=aw.device
              join (select a.id,a.device,a.protocol,concat(replace(group_concat(a.portshow),',',';&lt;br /&gt;'),';') port from
                                 (select pa5.id,pa5.device,ap3.protocol,case when substr(ap3.destination_port,1,instr(ap3.destination_port,'-')-1)=substr(ap3.destination_port,instr(ap3.destination_port,'-')+1) then substr(ap3.destination_port,1,instr(ap3.destination_port,'-')-1) else ap3.destination_port end portshow
                                  from policy_application pa5 join application ap3 on pa5.device=ap3.device and pa5.application=ap3.name
                                  where pa5.device=#{deviceName}
                                  union
                                  select pa6.id,pa6.device,ap4.protocol,case when substr(ap4.destination_port,1,instr(ap4.destination_port,'-')-1)=substr(ap4.destination_port,instr(ap4.destination_port,'-')+1) then substr(ap4.destination_port,1,instr(ap4.destination_port,'-')-1) else ap4.destination_port end portshow
                                  from policy_application pa6 join application_set aps3 on pa6.application=aps3.name and pa6.device=aps3.device
                                                                     join application ap4 on aps3.application=ap4.name and aps3.device=ap4.device
                                                                     where pa6.device=#{deviceName}
                                  union
                                  select pa7.id,pa7.device,apt2.protocol,case when substr(apt2.destination_port,1,instr(apt2.destination_port,'-')-1)=substr(apt2.destination_port,instr(apt2.destination_port,'-')+1) then substr(apt2.destination_port,1,instr(apt2.destination_port,'-')-1) else apt2.destination_port end portshow
                                  from policy_application pa7 join application_set aps4 on pa7.application=aps4.name and pa7.device=aps4.device
                                                                     join application_term apt2 on aps4.application=apt2.name and aps4.device=apt2.device
                                                                     where pa7.device=#{deviceName}                                           
                                  union
                                  select pa8.id,pa8.device,am8.protocol,case when am8.portvalue is null then '' else concat('#',am8.portvalue) end portshow
                                  from policy_application pa8 join application_map am8 on pa8.application=am8.name
                                  where pa8.device=#{deviceName}
                                  ) a
                    group by a.id,a.device,a.protocol) aw2 on p.id=aw2.id and p.device=aw2.device
              where p.device=#{deviceName} and p.status=#{status} and p.action=#{action}
              order by p.id+0
              limit ${start},${rows}
```

Comment: An example of one of the statements would be helpful in answering, or the database structure.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQLServer?, because the tags are confusing

Comment: Just because the query is hard to read does not mean it has be optimized. But of course mysql does struggle with very large queries so breaking it up into a few smaller queries might sometimes work. For larger queries postgresql is the beast

Answer (score 0):

If you're on MySQL, first of all, I'd read the reference documentation about what [an execution plan is](http://Understanding%20the%20Query%20Execution%20Plan).

You should understand the plan that the server executes when it runs your query. There you can see if the server is using the indexes you have, or if you need to add new indexes, for example.

There are several things you can do to optimize your queries. It could be, for example denormalize your structure or normalize it... (It depends on the query). Add more indexes if the updates are not critical, partitionate tables, etc.

So the first of all is tu use the *EXPLAIN* and *EXPLAIN EXTENDED* commands before a query:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT ...
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT ...
```

form there you can see what's happening under the hood of your query and make the changes you think will improve the performance.

Answer (score 0):

First step: try to use views or stored procedure in order to make it more readable.

Next step: check which query is the bottle neck of the statements by using query plan or running each view/query/stored procedure by itself and checking running time

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that is some piece of SQL, being a ~40 table join.

Given its complexity I am struggling to see any obvious ways to increase performance in a big way.

Using EXPLAIN might help, but with the number of sub queries you are using it will probably just complain about most of those (as it will not use indexes joining sub queries - same applies to view which might make it more readable but would likely not help performance and might hinder it).

There are a few minor tweaks. For the sub query **aw** you have an extra query around the main sub query that is just doing a DISTINCT. As the main sub query is 4 unioned queries, the UNION statement will have already eliminated the duplicates. Hence the outer query to do the DISTINCT is redundant.

Further point. Your main query is checking against the policy table. I presume this massively reduces the number of records to process, but each of your sub queries is returning large numbers of rows which will not match this. It might well be quicker to do extra joins against policy in each sub query to reduce the records each sub query returns (and do it at a level where indexes can be used).

So something like this:-

```
SELECT p.id,p.from_zone fromzone,p.to_zone tozone,p.action,p.status,saw.srcaddr,daw.dstaddr,aw2.protocol,CASE WHEN aw2.port=';' then ' ' else aw2.port end port                            
FROM policy p 
JOIN 
(
    SELECT sa.id,sa.device,CONCAT(REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(sa.nameshow),',',';&lt;br /&gt;'),';') srcaddr 
    FROM                                          
    (
        SELECT sai.id,sai.device,sai.nameshow,max(sai.flag) flagw 
        FROM
        (
            SELECT psa1.id,psa1.device,a1.network nameshow,CASE WHEN a1.from_network&lt;=#{srcAddr} AND a1.to_network&gt;=#{srcAddr} then 1 else 0 end flag 
            FROM policy p 
            JOIN policy_source_destination_addr psa1 ON p.id=psa1.id AND p.device=#{deviceName} AND p.status=#{status} AND p.action=#{action}
            JOIN address a1 ON psa1.address=a1.name AND psa1.device=a1.device AND psa1.zone=a1.zone 
            WHERE psa1.device=#{deviceName} AND psa1.direction='source'
            UNION
            SELECT psa2.id,psa2.device,psa2.address nameshow,CASE WHEN a2.from_network&lt;=#{srcAddr} AND a2.to_network&gt;=#{srcAddr} then 1 else 0 end flag 
            FROM policy p 
            JOIN policy_source_destination_addr psa2 ON p.id=psa2.id AND p.device=#{deviceName} AND p.status=#{status} AND p.action=#{action}
            JOIN address_set as1 ON psa2.address=as1.name AND psa2.device=as1.device AND psa2.zone=as1.zone
            JOIN address a2 ON as1.device=a2.device AND as1.zone=a2.zone AND as1.address=a2.name
            WHERE psa2.device=#{deviceName} AND psa2.direction='source'
            UNION
            SELECT psa3.id,psa3.device,psa3.address nameshow,CASE WHEN a5.from_network&lt;=#{srcAddr} AND a5.to_network&gt;=#{srcAddr} then 1 else 0 end flag 
            FROM policy p 
            JOIN policy_source_destination_addr psa3 ON p.id=psa3.id AND p.device=#{deviceName} AND p.status=#{status} AND p.action=#{action}
            JOIN address_set as3 ON psa3.address=as3.name AND psa3.device=as3.device AND psa3.zone=as3.zone
            JOIN address_set as4 ON as3.device=as4.device AND as3.zone=as4.zone AND as3.address=as4.name
            JOIN address a5 ON as4.device=a5.device AND as4.zone=a5.zone AND as4.address=a5.name
            WHERE psa3.device=#{deviceName} AND psa3.direction='source'
            UNION
            SELECT psa3.id,psa3.device,psa3.address nameshow,1 flag 
            FROM policy p 
            JOIN policy_source_destination_addr psa3 ON p.id=psa3.id AND p.device=#{deviceName} AND p.status=#{status} AND p.action=#{action}
            WHERE psa3.device=#{deviceName} AND psa3.direction='source' AND upper(psa3.address)='ANY'
        ) sai
        GROUP BY sai.id,sai.device,sai.nameshow
    ) sa
    GROUP BY sa.id,sa.device 
    HAVING MAX(sa.flagw)=1
) saw 
ON p.id=saw.id AND p.device=saw.device
JOIN 
(
    SELECT da.id,da.device,CONCAT(REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(da.nameshow),',',';&lt;br /&gt;'),';') dstaddr 
    FROM
    (
        SELECT dai.id,dai.device,dai.nameshow,max(dai.flag) flagw 
        FROM
        (
            SELECT pda1.id,pda1.device,a3.network nameshow,CASE WHEN a3.from_network&lt;=#{dstAddr} AND a3.to_network&gt;=#{dstAddr} then 1 else 0 end flag 
            FROM policy p 
            JOIN policy_source_destination_addr pda1  ON p.id=pda1.id AND p.device=#{deviceName} AND p.status=#{status} AND p.action=#{action}
            JOIN address a3 ON pda1.address=a3.name AND pda1.device=a3.device AND pda1.zone=a3.zone where pda1.device=#{deviceName} AND pda1.direction='destination'
            union
            SELECT pda2.id,pda2.device,pda2.address nameshow,CASE WHEN a4.from_network&lt;=#{dstAddr} AND a4.to_network&gt;=#{dstAddr} then 1 else 0 end flag 
            FROM policy p 
            JOIN policy_source_destination_addr pda2  ON p.id=pda2.id AND p.device=#{deviceName} AND p.status=#{status} AND p.action=#{action}
            JOIN address_set as2 ON pda2.address=as2.name AND pda2.device=as2.device AND pda2.zone=as2.zone
            JOIN address a4 ON as2.device=a4.device AND as2.zone=a4.zone AND as2.address=a4.name
            WHERE pda2.device=#{deviceName} AND pda2.direction='destination'
            UNION
            SELECT pda3.id,pda3.device,pda3.address nameshow,CASE WHEN a6.from_network&lt;=#{dstAddr} AND a6.to_network&gt;=#{dstAddr} then 1 else 0 end flag 
            FROM policy p 
            JOIN policy_source_destination_addr pda3  ON p.id=pda3.id AND p.device=#{deviceName} AND p.status=#{status} AND p.action=#{action}
            JOIN address_set as5 ON pda3.address=as5.name AND pda3.device=as5.device AND pda3.zone=as5.zone
            JOIN address_set as6 ON as5.device=as6.device AND as5.zone=as6.zone AND as5.address=as6.name
            JOIN address a6 ON as6.device=a6.device AND as6.zone=a6.zone AND as6.address=a6.name
            WHERE pda3.device=#{deviceName} AND pda3.direction='destination'
            UNION
            SELECT pda3.id,pda3.device,pda3.address nameshow,1 flag 
            FROM policy p 
            JOIN policy_source_destination_addr pda3  ON p.id=pda3.id AND p.device=#{deviceName} AND p.status=#{status} AND p.action=#{action}
            WHERE pda3.device=#{deviceName} AND pda3.direction='destination' AND upper(pda3.address)='ANY'
        ) dai
        GROUP BY dai.id,dai.device,dai.nameshow
    ) da
    GROUP BY da.id,da.device 
    HAVING MAX(da.flagw)=1
) daw 
ON p.id=daw.id AND p.device=daw.device
join 
(
    SELECT pa1.id,pa1.device
    FROM policy p 
    JOIN policy_application pa1  ON p.id=pa1.id AND p.device=#{deviceName} AND p.status=#{status} AND p.action=#{action}
    JOIN application ap1 ON pa1.device=ap1.device AND pa1.application=ap1.name
    WHERE pa1.device=#{deviceName} AND upper(ap1.protocol)=#{protocol} AND if(INSTR(ap1.destination_port,'-')=0,ap1.destination_port=#{port},SUBSTR(ap1.destination_port,1,INSTR(ap1.destination_port,'-')-1)+0&lt;=#{port} AND SUBSTR(ap1.destination_port,INSTR(ap1.destination_port,'-')+1)+0&gt;=#{port})
    UNION
    SELECT pa2.id,pa2.device
    FROM policy p 
    JOIN policy_application pa2  ON p.id=pa2.id AND p.device=#{deviceName} AND p.status=#{status} AND p.action=#{action}
    JOIN application_set aps1 ON pa2.application=aps1.name AND pa2.device=aps1.device
    JOIN application ap2 ON aps1.application=ap2.name AND aps1.device=ap2.device
    WHERE pa2.device=#{deviceName} AND upper(ap2.protocol)=#{protocol} AND if(INSTR(ap2.destination_port,'-')=0,ap2.destination_port=#{port},SUBSTR(ap2.destination_port,1,INSTR(ap2.destination_port,'-')-1)+0&lt;=#{port} AND SUBSTR(ap2.destination_port,INSTR(ap2.destination_port,'-')+1)+0&gt;=#{port})
    UNION
    SELECT pa3.id,pa3.device
    FROM policy p 
    JOIN policy_application pa3  ON p.id=pa3.id AND p.device=#{deviceName} AND p.status=#{status} AND p.action=#{action}
    JOIN application_set aps2 ON pa3.application=aps2.name AND pa3.device=aps2.device
    JOIN application_term apt1 ON aps2.application=apt1.name AND aps2.device=apt1.device
    WHERE pa3.device=#{deviceName} AND upper(apt1.protocol)=#{protocol} AND if(INSTR(apt1.destination_port,'-')=0,apt1.destination_port=#{port},SUBSTR(apt1.destination_port,1,INSTR(apt1.destination_port,'-')-1)+0&lt;=#{port} AND SUBSTR(apt1.destination_port,INSTR(apt1.destination_port,'-')+1)+0&gt;=#{port})
    UNION
    SELECT pa4.id,pa4.device
    FROM policy p 
    JOIN policy_application pa4  ON p.id=pa4.id AND p.device=#{deviceName} AND p.status=#{status} AND p.action=#{action}
    JOIN application_map am4 ON pa4.application=am4.name
    WHERE pa4.device=#{deviceName} AND upper(am4.protocol)=#{protocol} AND (if(am4.portvalue is null,1=1,if(length(am4.portvalue)-length(replace(am4.portvalue,'#',''))=2,SUBSTRING_INDEX(am4.portvalue, '#', 1)+0&lt;=#{port} AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(am4.portvalue, '#', -2), '#', 1)+0&gt;=#{port},SUBSTRING_INDEX(am4.portvalue, '#', 1)+0=#{port} or SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(am4.portvalue, '#', -2), '#', 1)+0=#{port})))
) aw 
ON p.id=aw.id AND p.device=aw.device
JOIN 
(
    SELECT a.id,a.device,a.protocol,CONCAT(REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(a.portshow),',',';&lt;br /&gt;'),';') port 
    FROM
    (
        SELECT pa5.id,pa5.device,ap3.protocol,CASE WHEN SUBSTR(ap3.destination_port,1,INSTR(ap3.destination_port,'-')-1)=SUBSTR(ap3.destination_port,INSTR(ap3.destination_port,'-')+1) then SUBSTR(ap3.destination_port,1,INSTR(ap3.destination_port,'-')-1) else ap3.destination_port end portshow
        FROM policy p 
        JOIN policy_application pa5  ON p.id=pa5.id AND p.device=#{deviceName} AND p.status=#{status} AND p.action=#{action}
        JOIN application ap3 ON pa5.device=ap3.device AND pa5.application=ap3.name
        WHERE pa5.device=#{deviceName}
        UNION
        SELECT pa6.id,pa6.device,ap4.protocol,CASE WHEN SUBSTR(ap4.destination_port,1,INSTR(ap4.destination_port,'-')-1)=SUBSTR(ap4.destination_port,INSTR(ap4.destination_port,'-')+1) then SUBSTR(ap4.destination_port,1,INSTR(ap4.destination_port,'-')-1) else ap4.destination_port end portshow
        FROM policy p 
        JOIN policy_application pa6  ON p.id=pa6.id AND p.device=#{deviceName} AND p.status=#{status} AND p.action=#{action}
        JOIN application_set aps3 ON pa6.application=aps3.name AND pa6.device=aps3.device
        JOIN application ap4 ON aps3.application=ap4.name AND aps3.device=ap4.device
        WHERE pa6.device=#{deviceName}
        UNION
        SELECT pa7.id,pa7.device,apt2.protocol,CASE WHEN SUBSTR(apt2.destination_port,1,INSTR(apt2.destination_port,'-')-1)=SUBSTR(apt2.destination_port,INSTR(apt2.destination_port,'-')+1) then SUBSTR(apt2.destination_port,1,INSTR(apt2.destination_port,'-')-1) else apt2.destination_port end portshow
        FROM policy p 
        JOIN policy_application pa7  ON p.id=pa7.id AND p.device=#{deviceName} AND p.status=#{status} AND p.action=#{action}
        JOIN application_set aps4 ON pa7.application=aps4.name AND pa7.device=aps4.device
        JOIN application_term apt2 ON aps4.application=apt2.name AND aps4.device=apt2.device
        WHERE pa7.device=#{deviceName}                                           
        UNION
        SELECT pa8.id,pa8.device,am8.protocol,CASE WHEN am8.portvalue is null then '' else concat('#',am8.portvalue) END portshow
        FROM policy p 
        JOIN policy_application pa8  ON p.id=pa8.id AND p.device=#{deviceName} AND p.status=#{status} AND p.action=#{action}
        JOIN application_map am8 ON pa8.application=am8.name
        WHERE pa8.device=#{deviceName}
    ) a
    GROUP BY a.id,a.device,a.protocol
) aw2 
ON p.id=aw2.id AND p.device=aw2.device
WHERE p.device=#{deviceName} AND p.status=#{status} AND p.action=#{action}
ORDER BY p.id+0
LIMIT ${start},${rows}
```

Answer (score 0):

- `order by  p.id+0` -- Is `id` a `VARCHAR` holding a number.  That hurts.
- `JOIN ( SELECT ... ) JOIN ( SELECT ... )` optimizes *very* poorly because those subqueries have no indexes.  Either reformulate the whole query, or use tmp tables to which you add indexes.
- `where  pa7.device=#{deviceName}` -- `policy_application` needs `INDEX(device)`.  Well, how about providing `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we know what indexes you already have.
- `where  psa1.device=#{deviceName} and  psa1.direction='source'` -- `policy_source_destination_addr` needs `INDEX(device, direction)` (in either order).

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to read not because it is is long, but because the lack of formatting makes it visually complex and hard to understand.

If anything, it should be broken out into more lines ...

```
select
  p.id                ,
  p.from_zone fromzone,
  p.to_zone   tozone  ,
  p.action            ,
  p.status            ,
  saw.srcaddr
```

Aim to make it readable by reducing the visual complexity that is preventing your brain from understanding the meaning ...

```
select psa3.id              ,
       psa3.device          ,
       psa3.address nameshow,
       case when a5.from_network <=#{srcAddr} and 
                 a5.to_network   <=#{srcAddr}
            then 1
            else 0
       end flag 
from   policy                         p 
join   policy_source_destination_addr psa3 on p.id         = psa3.id       and
                                              p.device     = #{deviceName} and 
                                              p.status     = #{status}     and
                                              p.action     = #{action}
join   address_set                    as3  on psa3.address = as3.name      and
                                              psa3.device  = as3.device    and
                                              psa3.zone    = as3.zone
join   address_s ...
```

The lower the level of visual complexity, the better your brain will be at recognising meaningful complexity in the code, such as joins on four columns, the presence of functions and case statements, the presence and values of column and table aliases etc..

Add inline comments where they would be helpful ... an example from my own code base ...

```
with
  cte_book_list as (
    -- retrieves a list of book_id's and the batch id
    -- we do this to provide a list of book_id's that can be used in a number of
    -- other CTE's below. The batch ID is included so this table doesn't have to be
    -- referenced again.
    select
      rb.id                             batch_id,
      rb.client_id                     client_id,
```

The number of lines is irrelevant. I have statements more than 500 lines long that are easy to read, understand, and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already know how to optimize normal-sized queries, and you just want some suggestion about how to tame the complexity of huge queries.

Recently I had to analyze and optimize some large views (>30 Joins).
I have created myself a couple of tools (still a draft, nothing that I'm willing to share at this phase)  that have helped me reaching a good result.

**Visualization**

I had been experimenting for a while with a [FoundationDB Java parser](https://github.com/rimig/sql-parser) fork so that I could parse the view and create a MindMap of the view structure ([FreeMind](http://freemind.sourceforge.net) has a simple xml based format). This has been really helpful as there were some patterns repeated here and there, and it was simple to recognize them on a graph.

> Even if you don't have a tool, it can be a good idea to draw a diagram
>   of the structure of the query in terms of tables and subqueries

(below an example drawn in Freemind.. the nodes with the "list" icon are actual tables).

[image]

**Divide et impera**

Try to decompose the query: look at every subquery of its own, every part of an union. Try to get what they were built for and do some experiment to simplify them or optimize them.

> A "local optimization" might not guarantee you big improvements, but this
>   phase is important to get acquainted with the large query in all its
>   parts.

**Test, test, test**

The local approach ("divide et impera") has also the benefit that you can test every single subquery on its own (if the total query is really slow, it would take time to test any regression on the total query). If all the parts of the query are returing the same rows, you can concentrate on make them work together more efficiently.

> Test your re-design in small manageable chunks

**Manage the query at an higher level**

Also for the "divide et impera" I found it useful to create my handmade tool: in this case, a "query compiler".

Basically I copied every single subquery in a file of its own, gave it the most meaningful name I could figure out, and used a library to be able to import the source of a subquery in the main query (I used Freemarker).

> The goal is to have a more "manegeable" SQL so that, after having
>   optimized the subqueries, you could analyze and optimize how the
>   subqueries were working together.

Alternatively, you can achieve the same result by creating views for the subqueries so that the high level query is simplified (I had not this possibility).